# AS3 get the contents of a dynamicaly chosen XML tag

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I need to retrieve the contents of an arbitrary tag within an XML data set via a string input

```
var example:XML =
<foo>
    <bar>
        baz
    </bar>
</foo>;
// i need to get baz by using the string "bar" in some way with foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the [`descendants`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#descendants%28%29) function available on XML variables, this will return a list of all instances, so for your example:

```
var tagInstanceList:XMLList = example.descendants("bar");
trace(tagInstanceList[0]) // baz
```

There's something to note about the index access here: The surrounding tags get omitted on index access for some reason, except when the found tag contains XML data.